# How do i deal with this traceback name error? This is my first script

Tags: python, linux, nameerror, traceback

The error is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./unzipemall3.py", line 14, in <module>
   sformat = parentFormat('start')
File "./unzipemall3.py", line 9, in parentFormat
   parent = input(where + " Folder name (ex. Mol1-A) : ")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mol8' is not defined
```

## !/usr/bin/env python

from os                 import chdir
from subprocess         import Popen, PIPE

def parentFormat(where):
    ## returns a list with the separator of '-'
    ## ex. Mol1-A returns [Mol1, A]
    # input for most parent folder
    parent = raw_input(where + " Folder name (ex. Mol1-A) : ")
    return parent.split('-')

if '**main**' == **name**:

```
sformat = parentFormat('Start')
eformat = parentFormat('End')

cp_dir_prop = {'mol': cformat[0][:3], 'number': '5', 'letter': 'A'}
cp_files = ['vi.job', 'numjob', 'ortho.inp', 'job']
cp_dir = cp_dir_prop['mol'] + cp_dir_prop['number'] + "-" + cp_dir_prop['letter']
cp_dir = '/'.join([cp_dir, cp_dir]) + "-1"

try:
    for i in range(0, cutInt(eformat[0])):
        cformat[0] = sformat[0][:3] + str(cutInt(sformat[0]))

        for j in range(0, ord(eformat[1])-64):
            cformat[1] = chr(ord(sformat[1]) + j)

            # ex. mkdir Mol8-A/Mol8-A-1
            directory = '-'.join(cformat) + '/' + '-'.join(cformat + ['1'])
            Popen(['mkdir', directory])

            # ex. cp [files from Mol5-A-1] Mol8-A-1/
            for cp_file in cp_files:
                Popen(['cp', '/'.join([cp_dir, cp_file]), directory + '/'])

            # ex. tar -xf Mol8-A
            Popen(['tar', '-xf', '-'.join(cformat) + ".tgz"])

            # rm charmm-gui
            Popen(['rm', 'charmm-gui'])

            # ex. cd Mol8-A
            chdir('-'.join(cformat))

            # sed -i -e '0,/dimensions/s/dimensions/!dimensions.' -e '5s/.*/DIMENS CHSIZE 1000000/' -e '68s/.*/DYNA CPT leap start time 0.002 nstep 25000 -/' step5.1_production.inp
            sed = ['sed', '-i']
            sed.extend(['-e', '5s/.*/DIMENS CHSIZE 1000000/'])
            sed.extend(['-e', '68s/.*/DYNA CPT leap start time 0.002 nstep 25000 -/'])
            sed.extend(['-e', '0,/dimensions/s/dimensions/!dimensions'])
            sed.extend(['step5.1_production.inp'])
            Popen(sed)

            # sed -i -e '3s/nodes=4/nodes=1/' -e '37s:.*:mpirun ~/charmm.c36a4.20140107.newcali4.fixhcali.grange.b < ortho.inp   >charmm.out:' job5
            sed = ['sed', '-i']
            sed.extend(['-e', '3s/nodes=4/nodes=1/'])
            sed.extend(['-e', '37s:.*:mpirun ~/charmm.c36a4.20140107.newcali4.fixhcali.grange.b < ortho.inp   >charmm.out:'])
            sed.extend(['job5'])
            Popen(sed)

            # msub -q backfill job5
            Popen(['msub', '-q', 'backfill', 'job5'])

            # cd ..
            chdir('..')

except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Comment: An error without seeing your code is not helpful. All we can say is that it is looking for a variable `mol8` that you apparently never set.

Comment: I encountered another error...                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./unzipemall3.py", line 17, in <module>
    cp_dir_prop = {'mol': cformat[0][:3], 'number': '5', 'letter': 'A'}
NameError: name 'cformat' is not defined

Comment: @FSUresearch: Then create another question that describes the error, and gives us enough information to answer it. And meanwhile, if Kevin's answer solved your first problem, accept his answer.

Comment: @FSUresearch: I'm willing to bet the problem there is the one Cyber suggested at the start. The `cformat` isn't coming from `input()`, but from your code; maybe there's a typo, or maybe you're getting the scope wrong, or something different, but whatever it is, we'll need to see the code (or, better, a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of the whole thing) to help you fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Python 2.7 or lower.

```
parent = input(where + " Folder name (ex. Mol1-A) : ")
```

On this line, if the user types `mol8`, [the interpreter will look for the variable `mol8`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) and try to assign it to `parent`. But this won't work because the variable `mol8` doesn't exist. If you want `parent` to contain the string value `"mol8"`, use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

```
parent = raw_input(where + " Folder name (ex. Mol1-A) : ")
```

Alternatively, upgrade to Python 3, where `raw_input` has been renamed to `input`.

Comment: Great answer. To the OP: If you're learning from a Python 3 tutorial, you really want to install Python 3.4, not 2.7. Python 2 and Python 3 are obviously closely related languages, but they're not exactly the same and you're going to run into a lot of little problems like this.

Comment: should i merely update my version of python? Im using python 2.6.6

Comment: @FSUresearch: If you want to learn Python 3, then yes, definitely install Python 3.4 and use that. (If you're on linux, OS X, or almost anything besides Windows, you can't really "upgrade", because your OS needs whichever version of Python it came with, but you can definitely install another version alongside the original.)

Comment: I cannot upgrade my version of python because I am using university facilities. Anyway to 'edit' my whole script and revert it to a version compatible with 2.6.6?

Comment: I do not know how to accept Kevin's response, but it did work.